# What are the qubit capabilities of Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure-quantum

I've always worked on IBM Cloud when I needed to deploy a quantum application to a NISQ devices.

However, though not an hardware expert, I was asked to explore Microsoft Azure, which I see offers IonQ and Quantinuum platforms access.

I'm however struggling to understand their capabilities. For instance, [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources) I can clearly see, for each device, how many qubits it has and what type of process it is. I'm looking for something similar on Azure cloud.

Comment: Depends on which provider you use, Azure is a cloud service that, as far as I know, does not have real QCs, they just allow you to send jobs to QCs by other companies (providers), like Quantinuum or IONQ. Here is a link for example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/quantum/#features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Sam_QC mentioned, through Azure it is possible to access to several external providers that Azure are working with. It looks like there is no 1 organized documentation with all the desired data inside like in IBM. But I'll post here what have I found.

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/qc-target-list) (updated to 09/06/2022) it's written that there are 2 available providers - IonQ and Quantinuum - both providing real quantum hardware and simulators, and if we care about real quantum computers only - there are 3 available:

- **IonQ:** one 11-qubits trapped-ion based quantum computer available. **[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/provider-ionq#targets) are the most detailed specs** that I found.
- **Quantinuum**: two trapped-ion based quantum computers are available. The **H1-1** model has 20 qubits, and the **H1-2** model has 12 qubits. **[Here](https://assets.website-files.com/617730fbcf7b7c387194556a/62a8f7244596df4d854c2222_Quantinuum%20H1%20Product%20Data%20Sheet%20v5%2014JUN22.pdf) you can find more detailed specs**, and [here](https://www.quantinuum.com/products/h1) you can find some more information.

In [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/overview-azure-quantum#quantum-cloud-solutions-available-on-azure-quantum) (updated to 01/08/2022) it looks like several more providers has been added, but without further information beside that (I guess it is very fresh, if someone reading this can elaborate in this issue it will be great). The important part:

> - Quantinuum: Trapped-ion system with high-fidelity, fully connected    qubits, low error rates, qubit reuse, and the ability to perform
>   mid-circuit measurements.
> - IONQ: Dynamically reconfigurable trapped-ion quantum computer for up    to 11 fully connected qubits, that lets you run a two-qubit gate
>   between any pair.
> - Pasqal: Neutral atom-based quantum processors operating at room    temperature, with long coherence times and impressive qubit
>   connectivity. You can pre-register today for Azure Quantum’s private
>   preview of Pasqal.
> - Rigetti: Gate-based superconducting processors will be available in    Azure Quantum soon and utilize Quantum Intermediate Representation
>   (QIR) to enable low latency and parallel execution. You can
>   pre-register today for Azure Quantum’s private preview of Rigetti.
> - Quantum Circuits, Inc: Full-stack superconducting circuits, with    real-time feedback that enables error correction, encoding-agnostic
>   entangling gates. You can pre-register today for Azure Quantum’s
>   private preview of QCI.